# Mouse, Mx Revolution Search to Paste Highlighted Text

Tags: command-line, mouse

I want to be able to map the 'search button' → XF86Search to middle mouse click.  Or at least replace the 'paste highlighted text' to use this as a key as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do just that with [btnx](http://packages.ubuntu.com/btnx) [image: Install btnx].

Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd>, enter `btnx-config` and hit <kbd>ENTER</kbd> to open the configuration screen.

Comment: really?  I'm running 64 bit Lucid and i get a Segmentation fault when trying to run btnx.  "Could not read the config manager file: No such file or directory"

Comment: Ahh looks like if you run it through the menu (Applications->system tools) it doesn't seg fault.  Seems like this works... have to reboot 'btn-x' to take effect.  Will keep you posted if there are any further issues.